# jquery ui theme creating custom jqueryui.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

When I download a jquery ui theme via themeroller I get a jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js file instead of the standard jquery-ui-1.10.4.js file that comes with a regular jquery ui download.

I am trying to understand what is changing in jqueryui.js file from theme download to download.  I was under the impression that nothing should change the .js file and that themes were just .css.  Is this not the case?

I did not apply any customizations to the theme I downloaded (starter theme) and then added just the .css to a page with the regular jqueryui linked up and the page didn't work.  When I tried with other themes though such as the hot-sneaks I did not have this problem.

I am asking this question because I would like to link to the jqueryui on a cdn and I just want to use the vanilla version.  Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything different other than the name. You could try running them though a compare tool to see if there are any differences.

Here is an online Comparer http://www.diffnow.com/

Comment: There are 7 differences coming up in that tool when I compare the regular version to the one downloaded with the "starter" theme version.  I'm not sure how to share that though because it is 15000 lines long.

Comment: I know what you mean. Have you tried just replacing the CSS and Image files? I'm pretty sure that I have interchanged them before.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do that and it doesn't work.  It's very strange as some functionality is there but the styling is just off.  It doesn't do it with other themes even if they create a custom juqueryui.js file.  It's driving me nuts!  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess I'm out of ideas then. Sorry.  I looked at my code and it appears that I am just using the custom.js file.